# Inject into a being injected class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Google guice for dependency injection in my application.
I have a class structure like this,

Example is taken from [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2403/google-guice-dependency-injection-example-tutorial)

This is my interface,

```
package com.journaldev.di.services;

@ImplementedBy(EmailService.class)
public interface MessageService {

    boolean sendMessage(String msg, String receipient);
}
```

Which I will implement here

```
package com.journaldev.di.services;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

//import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class EmailService implements MessageService {

    public boolean sendMessage(String msg, String receipient) {
        //some fancy code to send email
        System.out.println("Email Message sent to "+receipient+" with message="+msg);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I inject EmailService here.

```
package com.journaldev.di.consumer;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.journaldev.di.services.MessageService;

public class MyApplication {

    private MessageService service;

    @Inject
    public void setService(MessageService svc){
        this.service=svc;
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String msg, String rec){
        //some business logic here
        return service.sendMessage(msg, rec);
    }
}
```

If suppose my EmailService class looked like this,

```
package com.journaldev.di.services;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

//import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class EmailService implements MessageService {
    public EmailService(int someValue) {
         FancyEmailService fancyEmailService = new FancyEmailService(someValue);
    }
    public boolean sendMessage(String msg, String receipient) {
        fancyEmailService.doSomething();
        System.out.println("Email Message sent to "+receipient+" with message="+msg);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In order to test the above EmailService code, I need to inject FancyEmailService than instantiating from the constructor. How do I inject FancyEmailService into EmailService code? and still be able to inject EmailService into MyApplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at these - https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings and https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods

```
public class GuiceTestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Integer.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("fancy"))
        .toInstance(10);
    }

    @Provides
    FancyEmailService fancyEmailServiceProvider(@Named("fancy") int i){
        return new FancyEmailService(i);
    }

}
```

My FancyEmailService & EMailService are as given below.

```
public class FancyEmailService {

    private final int i;

    public FancyEmailService(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("i is injected with " + i);
    }

}

@Singleton
public class EmailService implements MessageService {

    private FancyEmailService fancyEmailService;

    @Inject
    public EmailService(@Named("fancy") int someValue){
       fancyEmailService = new FancyEmailService(someValue);
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String msg, String receipient) {
        //some fancy code to send email
        System.out.println("Email Message sent to "+receipient+" with message="+msg);
        fancyEmailService.doSomething();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lets test

```
public class GuiceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceTestModule());

        MyApplication appn = injector.getInstance(MyApplication.class);
        appn.sendMessage("msg", "guru");
    }

}
```

output:

```
Email Message sent to guru with message=msg
i is injected with 10
```

EmailService can also be written this way using @Provides

```
@Singleton
public class EmailService implements MessageService {

    private FancyEmailService fancyEmailService;

    @Inject
    public EmailService(FancyEmailService fes){
       fancyEmailService = fes;
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String msg, String receipient) {
        //some fancy code to send email
        System.out.println("Email Message sent to "+receipient+" with message="+msg);
        fancyEmailService.doSomething();
        return true;
    }
}
```